# Free, automated OS-independent update management solutions

Tags: updates, wsus

I know it is possible (with OCS Inventory or WSUS for instance) to manage client systems' and applications' updates.

However, with OCS Inventory you have to use packages to execute scripts on client computers. This means that each update to deploy is a script to create or update.

With WSUS it is nearly the same: WSUS manages Microsoft applications automatically but if you want to update Flash or Java, you will need to do something like creating a specific GPO for each new versions.

So, my question is: is it possible to manage, from one central server, clients updates (Windows or Linux and system or applications) without creating a new package for each new deployement to do ?

The solution must be open-source or requiring a simple Windows server licence.

I heard about websites helping with creation of installation packages. There is WSUS too, but it is for Microsoft systems and applications only...

This is a problem every sysadmin should encounter, what are current solutions ? (I agree admins are born to do that. OCS helps already a lot)

I'm wondering if using WSUS for Microsoft and OCS Inventory for everything else is the best "free" solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are two products available that extend WSUS to provide updates for third-party Windows applications:

- [Secunia CSI](http://www.secunia.com)
- [SolarWinds Patch Manager](http://www.solarwinds.com/patch-manager.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, good idea to try to extend WSUS. I did not already think about that part of the solution.

Secunia CSI would be redundant with the OCS (inventory tool) client agent. Workstations don't have much power.

And Patch Manager seams great but is out of question because of the price.